# SwiftUI - StateObject in a row subview is initialised and deinit multiple times when scrolling

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to add a `StateObject` to a subview of a row displayed in a sectioned list in order to perform some work and update the subview when a `@Published` property from the `StateObject` is updated (e.g. download an image). The work should be performed when the subview appears (`.onAppear { }`).

The row is initialised once, and appears / disappears when scrolling. When adding items, the view is initialised again (not necessarily redrawn but that's normal if nothing changed). Similarly, the subview is initialised once, and appears / disappears when scrolling. When adding items, the view is initialised again (not necessarily redrawn but that's normal if nothing changed).

But the `StateObject` from the subview is initialised and deinit multiple times when I scroll. It should not as it's a `StateObject` and not an `ObservedObject`. Why is that happening?

[image]

When I add this `StateObject` to the row instead, the `StateObject` is correctly initialised once (even when adding new items to the list) and is never deinit.

[image]

Sample code provided below .

```
import SwiftUI

struct SectionTest: Identifiable {
    var id: String { title }
    var title: String
    var items = [Item]()
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    var name: String
    var section: String
}

class Loader: ObservableObject {
    private var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("Loader • init \(name)")
    }
    
    func load() {
        print("Loader • load \(name)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Loader • deinit \(name)")
    }
}

struct LoaderView: View {
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        print("LoaderView • init \(name)")
        self.name = name
        self._loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(name: "LoaderView ".appending(name)))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 200)
            .onAppear { loader.load() }
            
            .onAppear {
                print("LoaderView • appear \(name)")
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("LoaderView • disappear \(name)")
            }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        print("RowView • init \(name)")
        self.name = name
        self._loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(name: "RowView ".appending(name)))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(name)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            LoaderView(name: name)
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("RowView • appear \(name)")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("RowView • disappear \(name)")
        }
    }
}

struct StateObjectListView: View {
    
    @State private var items = [
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "First"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "First"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "First"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "Second"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "Second"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "Third"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "Third"),
        Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: "Third")
    ]
    
    private var sections: [SectionTest] {
        Dictionary(grouping: items) { $0.section }
            .map { SectionTest(title: $0.key, items: $0.value.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) }
            .sorted { $0.title < $1.title }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Add") {
                    let section = ["First", "Second", "Third"].randomElement()!
                    items.append(Item(name: UUID().uuidString, section: section))
                }
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(sections) { section in
                            Section(header: Text(section.title).font(.caption2)) {
                                ForEach(section.items) { item in
                                    RowView(name: item.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StateObject is not appropriate in this scenario, because List reuses row views for data from container.

Comment: So what would be the correct way to fetch an image for a row? At the row level instead of having that in a subview of my row?